# How do I plot weather data from two data sets on one bar graph using python?

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, visualization

Python newbie here.  I'm looking at some daily weather data for a couple of cities over the course of a year. [Each city has its own csv file](https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/data/tree/master/us-weather-history).  I'm interested in comparing the count of daily average temperatures between two cities in a bar graph, so I can see (for example) how often the average temperature in Seattle was 75 degrees (or 30 or 100) compared to Phoenix.

I'd like a bar graph with side-by-side bars with temperature on the x-axis and count on the y-axis. I've been able to get a bar graph of each city separately with this data, but don't know how to get both cities on the same bar chart with with a different color for each city. Seems like it should be pretty simple, but my hours of search haven't gotten me a good answer yet.

Suggestions please, oh wise stackoverflow mentors?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv("KSEA.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("KPHX.csv")

df["actual_mean_temp"].value_counts(sort=False).plot(kind ="bar")
df2["actual_mean_temp"].value_counts(sort = False).plot(kind = 'bar')
```

Comment: The contents of those CSV files would be helpful in testing out possible solutions.

Comment: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html  This will make it pretty easy

Comment: Looks like you want to plot temperature distribution. This kind of figure does not superpose well when using bar charts. Use KDE instead or subplots sharing X axis.

Comment: Henry Ecker, the files are here: https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/data/tree/master/us-weather-history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `concat` DataFrames, `assign`ing city as a column, and then use `histplot` in `seaborn`:

```
import seaborn as sns

z = pd.concat([
    df[['actual_mean_temp']].assign(city='KSEA'),
    df2[['actual_mean_temp']].assign(city='KPHX'),
])

ax = sns.histplot(data=z, x='actual_mean_temp', hue='city',
                  multiple='dodge', binwidth=1)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks, this is awesome! Can you give me some tips on how you figured this out? I'd love to get better at solving these issues on my own, I'm just not sure how to do that besides googling answers, and that option didn't work great for me. What's the process you used to get this answer/code?

Comment: @cyoung With `seaborn` plots specifically, I think you can have a look at their [Example gallery](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/index.html). A quick and easy way to get a good understanding of what you can do with it, and there's code under each example, so you can also see how to do it. I found it very useful. And their [tutorial](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial.html) is also very good